# Android - NFC tag detect when user in some other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, nfc

I used the NFC tag for application launching.but when other activities are running and  i touch the tag to device the NFC application is launching again.

**manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.testnfc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.testnfc.TestNFCActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.testnfc.NFCLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />



            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.test.testnfc.FirstActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.test.testnfc.SecondActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.test.testnfc.ThirdActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.test.testnfc.FourthActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.test.testnfc.FifthActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't want this.Instead it should stay in the same activity.
Any idea about this?

Answer (score 2):

Move the intent-filter for NFC detection into a Service, so that when a tag is discovered a Service is started instead of an Activity.

You can then use the Service to decide what you want to do and which Activity to launch.

Comment: @Raghav Sood i have same problem will u help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try set this properties in manifest for that activity:

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Hope it will help.